# Wildcard key on this scope inside a class with Typescript gives "property [x] does not exist on type..."

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a small npm package that groups all items inside one class so I can do something to every item in said class via the group (For example: I want to be able to individually call `item.set(xx)` but I want to be able to be able to do it via a group aswell (`group.item.set(xx)`) so I can basically make a function inside my group class that would set `xx` to all items in said group.

I have a dummy below which is used in the same manner (but very much stripped for this purpose). As you can see I give my `Group` class an object with a key and a `GroupItem`. In the constructor I then alias the key to be readily available via some kind of a shorthand (`this[k] = items[k]` which basically means I can do `group.first` instead of `group.items.first`.

This, however, throws an error because when I try to call `group.first` after initializing the class it says `Key first does not exist on type....`. Which is true, but I don't want my VScode to make a big hassle out of it because I want to be able to use any name(`first`, `second` or `toilet` or whatever inside that group)

I've tried adding this to my `GroupInterface`

```
[key: string]: GroupItem; // or any/unknown/never, ive tried them all
```

without success (`const group` only seems to see what's inside the class and skips the Interface on intellisense)

Adding the above straight into my class does work somewhat; it won't show the error for `second` but gives other issues such as (`Property 'items' of type 'GroupItem[]' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'GroupItem'.ts(2411)`) and makes it a pain to actually use inside some code due to the extra typecasting you'll have to do to see if `group.second` is not secretly an array etc.

```
class GroupItem {
  name = 'A group item';
}

interface GroupItemInGroup {
  [key: string]: GroupItem;
}

interface GroupInterface {
  apply(): void;
}

class Group implements GroupInterface {
  items: GroupItem[];

  constructor(items: GroupItemInGroup) {
    this.items = [];

    // key the `items` object so we can create a shorthand (group.first)
    Object.keys(items).forEach((k) => {
      this.items.push(items[k]);
      this[k] = items[k];
    });
  }

  apply(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

These(obviously) throw the error `Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Group'.ts(2339)`:

```
const theGroup = new Group({
  first: new GroupItem(),
  second: new GroupItem(),
});

console.log(theGroup.first);
console.log(theGroup.second);
```

In short:
Is there a way I can use whatever key I want and map directly to my `this` scope without vscode telling me that that key does not exist?

Comment: Classes/interfaces in TS require statically-known keys, and an index signature is not specific enough for your needs.  Do you *need* to use a class here?  If not I'd suggest refactoring to a factory function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAgEvw).  If so then you'll need to use a lot of type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpA7gW) to get it working.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I've fixed it with the type-assertion example you've given me. It required some lint disabling and it doesn't make it very readable but it does seem to be the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you want `Group` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the keys of the `items` constructor argument, like `class Group<K> implements Record<K, GroupItem> {⋯}` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)).  But that's not allowed in TypeScript; interfaces and classes require *statically known keys*, and `K` is not statically known.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#2225](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225) and [microsoft/TypeScript#21326](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21326).

---

If you can give up on using a class and write a factory function instead, this is relatively straightforward to write:

```
function Group<K extends PropertyKey>(items: Record<K, GroupItem>) {
    const _items: { [k: string]: GroupItem } = items; // widen
    return {
        ...items,
        items: [...Object.values(_items)],
        apply(): void {
            throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
        }
    }
}
/* function Group<K extends PropertyKey>(items: Record<K, GroupItem>
     ): Record<K, GroupItem> & { items: GroupItem[]; apply(): void; }} */
```

The returned object's type is automatically computed by TypeScript to be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the pieces of the object literal.  Now when you call it (instead of `new`) you get the desired behavior:

```
const theGroup = Group({
    first: new GroupItem(),
    second: new GroupItem(),
});

console.log(theGroup.first); // okay
console.log(theGroup.second); // okay
console.log(theGroup.items); // okay
try { theGroup.apply() } catch (e) { console.log(e) } // okay
```

---

If you *need* to use a class then you have to fake it up by writing the closest class you can to what you want, rename it out of the way (e.g., `_Group`), and then use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you have a `Group` class constructor whose instances are the same generic intersection from the factory function version.  For example:

```
class _Group {
    items: GroupItem[];

    constructor(items: GroupItemInGroup) {
        this.items = [];
        Object.keys(items).forEach((k) => {
            this.items.push(items[k]);
            (this as Group<any>)[k] = items[k];
        });
    }

    apply(): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
}
type Group<K extends PropertyKey> = _Group & Record<K, GroupItem>;
const Group = _Group as new <K extends PropertyKey>(
    items: Record<K, GroupItem>) => Group<K>;
```

Inside the implementation of `_Group` the compiler doesn't expect `this` to have arbitrary `string` keys so we need an assertion to make `this[k]` work.  And then the `Group` value is just the same as `_Group`, but we've asserted that its type is of a generic [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) producing a `Group<K>` instance, where `Group<K>` is the relevant intersection of `Group` instance types and `Record<K, GroupItem>`.

Now it behaves as you wanted initially:

```
const theGroup = new Group({
    first: new GroupItem(),
    second: new GroupItem(),
});

console.log(theGroup.first); // okay
console.log(theGroup.second); // okay
console.log(theGroup.items); // okay
try { theGroup.apply() } catch (e) { console.log(e) }  // okay
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7ArgBwJIBcCmBbaA3gLABQ050AdmLttALzQDkAgtAOZJrQCWOuTANykAvqVI9KOeADMwwOghQZ+6Sku7EyFANoBrbAE8AXNAiZ4k9gF1TGlXmEkxJUtVoRU8ugDF5mRHhDH2RKYEweREpCcW1yGVDwyOj7AB4AaWhsAA8cSgATGAAFJFRseExDdKMAPgAKPjwIUwAlbGBA-IyAGjguB1wagEoYuIpyDspzaAB9Rtxmwmh9U3NLShs7fqw8aBEGXn4IQWgAelPoAHcefOxKUnHx+GxMZHhorUev6AA6P-mIN0Ht9xgDTDo-j8APIAIwAVu1MD8AG5gEDIbAQOpzI5DaxAsYgsCoVAgQx1IamZGIG6jEEgzAACyQlyo2FZAFF4Eh4HUmABZF6MxD5KiITC8XCkvB3HD5H5MIZOekUFwgtWq4HkU4AKmgCTCESifWUGSyuTuhWgJUQZQqVVqDSOrXanR6JrQO0GWq+lOgbQ68C66V69i9NWgADIlmCPQMdNYTsTSeS-dSbicRPsdadYj7JtMmdh7Ad7HVPt8ZDx4OZTJR2XGvRSCSCIK6CnWG2H+M2fSIlbFxgXECBsD8QIh2HUi-YflWa5glWcLog9GBDPmohAR2OJ1OZ-0fm3Jvkl+doKv15upjvx5Pp4zi4eAWeV2uN2MLIYlgflD9k2SFJ7NAwBgJgwCMtAdTYCMBAgVut57tBIz7Oel4fi4bg0JiXgKNAADqgRrlwBQ+IEADC4BQKM+ZUTAMwlhWXyxt2eAJk4PpDluFjIOEgROk0WzKF6aj2LBnHfEyPAQD8AIHOxElfLCCLhD8BiGFiL5zoEHLyIydR1HoIz0BGTEqhQUkyQCPyoMgED6QC+jWAOhLmQ+0nQJAcapGAlCGMMTkHI5eiJopjz9sq3yYa55AAamVI0qKZkMsyiCsvWnLcvxApCiKYoSjwUqjrQUjYPKiqRV8GrkNV0CVGU3mZDkeRWjadqVNU-kHAx-RRv6rpBu6rGDJV8FTBKJaMD1yieTAGXQGazWWsUpTlB1jphbGAZuiGjb8MMDARmk6Q1BxYwFhKv7cIw81lslFDzrWbKssNvYxWY7b5J2L3bD2QwtqqLnXtuo53vuj6zo9i4nGh77A4h95XagR6fa+F5w+dCGg0hSOybiMNvlen5BD+EOHnFQH7KB4GQchSzDtj94wcBy7o0TsQiEAA)